# Having Problems Setting up Rundeck Ansible Node (Folder Permissions)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, chmod, rundeck

I'm trying to setup an Ansible in Rundeck.

But I get the Error: (**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**)

The Node Source had an error:

```
ERROR: Ansible IO failure: Cannot run program "/etc/ansible/ansible-playbook" (in directory "/tmp/rundeck/ansible-hosts4006878119537487113"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

When I look at `/tmp/rundeck` and do an `ls -l`, I see that the folder was created, but with the wrong permissions.

So my question is, can I define in Ansible or Rundeck what permission they set when they create a folder?

Comment: Do you have ansible installed? Rundeck and Ansible must coexist in the same server, you're facing this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5880 Basically install Ansible and make sure that the rundeck user can reach the Ansible binaries, inventory and config file. Additionally, check this amazing step by step guide: https://jwkenney.github.io/ansible-rundeck-integration/

Comment: Hello @MegaDrive68k yes Rundeck and Ansible are installed on the same server and the tutorial you sent didn't help me either

Comment: Hi Laurin, can you access the ansible binaries from the rundeck user account, could you check that?